# How to use an external variables file inside a script

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

Is it possible read variables from a file and sent it to a bash script via Parallel?

Example:

I have a file called data.txt with the following content:

```
apple red
banana yellow
grape green
```

Id like to read this file using Parallel and run a bash script using each line as variable.
The result of this script must be:

```
Fruit: apple
Color: red

Fruit banana
Color: yellow

Fruit: grape
Color: green
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
parallel -a  data.txt --colsep ' ' ./script
```

Where `script` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Fruit: $1"
echo -e "Colour: $2"
```

You will get the same result with a slightly different syntax, depending on how you like to see things:

```
cat data.txt | parallel --colsep ' ' ./script {1} {2}
```